# Difference of Image.rotate on PIL/Pillow 2.8.1 and 3.1.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I was having a bad time with `Image.rotate()` on `PIL` until I decided to check on a terminal what was going on. This is what I did:

**Python 2, Pillow (2.8.1)**

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.new('RGB', (800, 500))
im.size
out = im.rotate(90)
out.size
```

Output (as expected):

```
>> (800, 500)
>> (500, 800)
```

**Python 3, Pillow (3.1.1)**

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.new('RGB', (800, 500))
im.size
out = im.rotate(90)
out.size
```

Output:

```
>> (800, 500)
>> (800, 500)
```

And I think that's the right way to call rotate in Pillow 3X. Here's the documentation for the function:
[Image.Rotate()](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html?highlight=rotate#PIL.Image.Image.rotate) Am I missing something?

Comment: https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/1500

Comment: @rmn thank you a lot. I wonder how I miss that in the searches I made. If you post and answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a bug in Pillow<=2.9.0, fixed in 3.0.0. If you want the image to change size when rotated, you need to include the expand argument, e.g. img.rotate(-90, expand=1). See [this issue](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/1500) for details.